# SVM strange classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, prediction

I would like to have a prediction of short term direction of a certain asset. I did an SVM model based on Dane_train data.frame (8058 rows):

```
SVM1 <- e1071::svm(Direction ~ logReturns_1,
               data = Dane_train,
               type = "C-classification",
               cost = 0.1,
               kernel = "linear",
               scale = FALSE)
```

And then I would like to make a prediction of the records from Dane_test data.frame:

```
pred <- predict(SVM1, data = Dane_test, method = "class")
```

The first strange thing is that I get factor vector of length 8058 - not 2015 from test data. Then when I do:

```
table(pred, Dane_test$Direction)
```

I have an error because of the inappriopriate length of the arguments. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for `predict` are a little different. You need `newdata=Dane_test` not `data=Dane_test`.